# User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application

Tags: error

I have created a User Profile Service Application in central admin. The service says it is starting but when you click on the link it returns the following:

> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID:
>   5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8

Looking in the log file I see the following corresponding to the Correlation ID.

```
User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   cm6y    High        User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   cm6y    High        User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   cm6y    High        User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   g22d    High        UserProfileApplication.DumpSynchronizationStatusToFile: Unexpected exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileConfigManager.IsSynchronizationRunning(UserProfileApplicationProxy userProfileApplicationProxy)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.DumpSynchronizationStatusToFile().   5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   et8j    High        UserProfileServiceUserStatisticsWebPart:LoadControl failed, Exception: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may not have been started. Please contact your administrator.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileAdminPage.get_CurrentApplicationProxy()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceStatisticsWebPartBase.LoadControl(Object sender, EventArgs e)    5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   et8j    High        UserProfileServiceAudienceStatisticsWebPart:LoadControl failed, Exception: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may not have been started. Please contact your administrator.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileAdminPage.get_CurrentApplicationProxy()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceStatisticsWebPartBase.LoadControl(Object sender, EventArgs e)    5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   et8j    High        UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart:LoadControl failed, Exception: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may not have been started. Please contact your administrator.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileAdminPage.get_CurrentApplicationProxy()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceStatisticsWebPartBase.LoadControl(Object sender, EventArgs e)  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
User Profiles                   cm6y    High        User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PartitionIDs()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.IsAvailable(SPServiceContext serviceContext)  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may not have been started. Please contact your administrator.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileAdminPage.get_CurrentApplicationProxy()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileAdminPage.IsProfileSynchronizationRunning()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart.RenderSectionContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.UserProfileServiceImportStatisticsWebPart.RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.Render(HtmlTextWriter ... 5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollectio...  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...n children)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  5205a398-eb54-462e-a9b1-4db39f92f1e8
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong and how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [Rational Guide to implementing SharePoint Server 2010 User Profile Synchronization](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx) and the follow the directions to the word. You should start with checking permissions, but most likely you will want to delete the service application and proxy and start from the beginning again.

I recently came across this error message and found that my application pool was the problem. After deleting the Service Application and recreating the service application and a new application pool with an account with the correct rights, this error message went away.